# SQL Convert total talktime (s) to MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

For my call center I need to calculate average talk time and display them in MM:SS.
I have the user involvement time in sec, and the total calls handled:

```
SELECT sum(usersinvolvedtime)/(sum(numansweredprim)+sum(numansweredover))AS 'Avg Handle time(s)'
FROM calltypefifteenmin
WHERE calltypekey IN (229,230,231,232,233,234,888,889,890,891)
and YEAR (recordtimestamp) = '2014'
AND Month (recordtimestamp) = '7'
```

As a result I get 238.
How to convert that into mm:ss ??

Many thanks in advance..!

Edwin

Comment: I'd advise performing the final conversion outside of the database. SQL Server only added a `time` data type in the 2008 version and even then, it represents a time of day, not a span of time. Other programming languages/libraries will tend to have a natural data type to represent this value and then perform formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(238/60 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST(238%60 AS VARCHAR) // 3:58
```

If you want exactly in `MM:SS` format

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(238 / 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(238 % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)                // 03:58
```

Comment: That is even better! Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Should be something along the following lines:

```
DECLARE @secs INT = 238;

SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),  @secs / 60)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  @secs % 60), 2);
```